# Union showing different results in CTE and Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find average number of times a user performed a search which led to a successful booking and the average number of times a user performed a search but did not lead to a booking. The output should have a column named action with values 'does not book' and 'books' as well as a 2nd column named average_searches with the average number of searches per action. Consider that the booking did not happen if the booking date is null. Search is connected to the booking only if their check-in dates match.

How do these 2 solutions differ? Cannot seem to figure out whats different
solution 1

```
with c1 as(
    select b.id_user, b.n_searches  
    from airbnb_contacts a
    join airbnb_searches b
    on a.ds_checkin = b.ds_checkin and a.id_guest = b.id_user
    where ts_booking_at is not null),
c2 as(
    select b.id_user, b.n_searches  
    from airbnb_contacts a
    join airbnb_searches b
    on a.ds_checkin = b.ds_checkin and a.id_guest = b.id_user
    where ts_booking_at isnull
)
select 'books' as action, avg(c1.n_searches) 
from c1
union 
select 'does not book' as action, avg(c2.n_searches) 
from c2
```

Output

```
books           23.333
does not book   28.383
```

Solution 2

```
select
    'does not book' as action,
    avg(n_searches) as average_number_of_search
from
    airbnb_searches as searches,
    airbnb_contacts as contacts
where
    contacts.ts_booking_at isnull and
    contacts.id_guest = searches.id_user

union

select
    'books' as action,
    avg(n_searches) as average_number_of_search
from
    airbnb_searches as searches,
    airbnb_contacts as contacts
where
    contacts.ts_booking_at is not null and
    contacts.id_guest = searches.id_user
```

Output

```
books                 20.133
does not book         23.578
```

Comment: in the first you have for the join another condition

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)